# How to get the API to test locally the server after docker-compose up?

Tags: ajax, api, docker, server, docker-compose

I want to test the server for AJAX request before pushing my code. I am running a docker server using the command `docker-compose -f docker-compose-withdb.yml up`. But I don't know what's the API I have to make requests to for testing it locally.

This is the output snippet I am getting after `docker-compose up`:

````
taskmaster_1    | 
taskmaster_1    | Waiting for rabbitmq:5672 to become available ... done
taskmaster_1    | rm: could not remove directory (code EBUSY): /tmp/runbox
rabbitmq_1      | 2019-05-22 08:02:48.857 [info] <0.657.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.657.0> (172.19.0.9:49598 -> 172.19.0.3:5672)```

I have tried making requests to localhost:5672 and 172.19.0.9:49598.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should map your api ports to Host. check docker-compose to see if there is a line like this:
`ports:
     - 80:8080`

which the first one is host port and the second one is container port.